# Find $ \lim {x\to 0, y\to 0} \frac {x^2 + sin y} {y^2 + sinx} $ for x, y belonging to the curve y=x^2

Tags: limits

I have done the following:

1. $  \lim_ {x→ 0, y→ 0} \frac {x^2+ \sin y} {y^2 + \sin x}$

= $ \lim _{x→ 0, y→ 0} \frac {y + \sin y} {x^4 + \sin x}$

= $ \frac {0} {0}, $using L'Hospital

= $  \lim_ {x→ 0, y→ 0} \frac{1+\cos y}{4x^3+\cos x}$

= $ 2$

2. $  \lim_ {x→ 0, y→ 0} \frac {x^2+\sin x^2}{x^4+\sin x} $

=$ \frac{0}{0}$, using L'Hospital

=$  \lim_ {x→ 0, y→ 0} \frac{2x+2x\cos x^2}{4x^3+\cos x} $

=$ \frac{0}{1}$

The correct answer is 2 but my query is what is the difference between the 2 methods \sin ce in both cases I am replacing one variable with the other?

Comment: Are you sure about the correct answer $2?$ 
Your first use of l'Hospital's rule is not legitimate. You need first to have only $x$ or only $y$ in the expression.

Comment: The given answer is 2. I am not sure about either of my methods, that's why I came here.

Comment: The "given answer" is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac {x^2 + \sin y} {y^2 + \sin x}$ along the parabola $y=x^2.$

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {x^2 + \sin x^2} {x^4 + \sin x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {x^2 \left(1+ \frac{\sin x^2}{x^2}\right)} {x\left(x^3 + \frac{\sin x}{x}\right)}=0,$$
because $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{x}=0,\;\;\; \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Along the curve $y=x^2$ we have for $|x|<\pi/2$

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x^2+\sin(y)}{y^2+\sin(x)}\right|&=\left|\frac{x^2+\sin(x^2)}{x^4+\sin(x)}\right|\\\\
&\le \frac{2x^2}{|\sin(x)|}\\\\
&\le \frac{2x^2}{|2x/\pi|}\\\\
&=\pi|x|
\end{align}$$

which clearly approaches zero as $x\to0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. If this was not useful, I am happy to delete it. Please let me know either way.